# Allow action from plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Is it possible to allow an plugin action in appController.php

I can't find and figure out how to do it. What I mean is, I know it is possible to use

```
$this->allow('action')
```

in the plugin's controller. But when I add it to the plugin's controller, once I update this plugin, I need to change the source again.

Is there a simpler way, eg. do this in appController.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the current `request` is to the plugin and controller you are targeting.

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    if($this->request->params['plugin'] == 'myplugin' && $this->request->params['controller'] == 'mycontroller')
    {
       $this->Auth->allow('action');
    }
}
```

I don't know if that code is correct, but it's something like that.